# Why do I have to use LD_PRELOAD for libcl.2 to use XML::LibXML::Common on HP/UX?

Tags: xml, perl, unix, shared-libraries, preloader

A compulsion of LD_PRELOAD on HP platform only and not on other unix flavors (AIX,Linux, and Solaris).

I built Perl Module [XML::LibXML::Common](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML-Common) on all of Unix flavors.I had to specifically do LD_PRELOAD for libcl.2 library on HP Platform only. While on other unix platforms nothing as such was required.

Is this an OS behaviour or something really missing in HP loader/compiler?

I was running a perl script which simply creates a new object of "XML::LibXML::SAX"

```
use XML::LibXML::SAX;
$x = XML::LibXML::SAX->new();
```

and it complained for

> Can't load 'site_perl/5.8.8/PA-RISC2.0-thread-multi/auto/XML/LibXML/Common/Common.sl' for module XML::LibXML::Common: Exec format error

and when i do the LD_PRELOAD for libcl.2 the error goes away and the Perl is built for a multi threaded support.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are asking why you have to use it.  If you are running Perl multi-threaded one of the libraries you are calling is getting loaded before libc and it is likely single threaded.  As part of its dependency processing, it is attempting to load a multi-threaded library in your environment.  By using LD_PRELOAD I think you are using the principle of library interposition to force that library to load prior to loading the unsafe library. The notion of interposition is a complex one and you might gain some benefit from the following [link](http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/lib_interposers.html):

**Excerpt:**

> To use library interposition, you need
>   to create a special shared library and
>   set the LD_PRELOAD environment
>   variable. When LD_PRELOAD is set, the
>   dynamic linker will use the specified
>   library before any other when it
>   searches for shared libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't clear...why did you have to use LD_PRELOAD?

Is it because HP-UX uses SHLIB_PATH instead of LD_LIBRARY_PATH, so you were setting the wrong environment variable?

It has other spellings on other platforms, too - Solaris and Linux happen to share much the same set of env. vars.  MacOS X uses DYLIB_LIBRARY_PATH; AIX uses use LIBPATH, I believe.

Comment: Yes I had to do LD_PRELOAD on HP.
I am not talking about environment for where to find the library with LIBPATHS (guess the synonyms vary as per OS).What I meant is, I had to specifically load a library and this is nothing to do with finding a library specifying in env variables.
hope i make sense.

Comment: Why did you have to load the library? Was it to override symbols from another library?  Is there a libcl.sl that you needed to replace? At the moment, you have not explained what went wrong before you did the LD_PRELOAD. So, I'm confused; the lack of other answers suggests others are too.

Answer (score 1):

Though this is an old subject, I'm seeing something similar on HP-UX right now.
In my case, it's not Perl, but while building Python's sqlite3 binding, dynamic loading of /usr/lib/libcl.2 is failing.

I've run the configure script with --with-libs='-lcl'. Though linking it to the binary and using LD_PRELOAD is not the same, both changes when /usr/lib/libcl.2 is loaded.
Since it solved mine, try that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is relevant, but it probably is.  THe Perl included with HP-UX is not the standard Perl but is a copy of ActiveState Perl - along with whatever strangeness that might include.  If you find Perl acting strangely on HP-UX in contrast to every other environment - check whether ActiveState Perl is at fault.